# Use Two rules for Htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This line is working

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)?$ site/$1/pagina.php?pagina=$2 [L]
```

Now I'm trying to make when accessing the link **/inicio** go to the **index.php** page.

```
RewriteRule ^inicio/(.*)?$ site/$1/index.php [L]
```

Thereby

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^site/

RewriteRule ^inicio/(.*)?$ site/$1/index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)?$ site/$1/pagina.php?pagina=$2 [L]
```

.

.

.

.
**Current code, with the help of friend @anubhava**

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/site/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]


RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/inicio?$ site/$1/index.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/noticia/([^/]+)/?$ site/$1/pagina.php?pagina=pag_noticiasVer.php&id=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ site/$1/pagina.php?pagina=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/site/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^inicio/([^/]+)/?$ site/$1/index.php [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ site/$1/pagina.php?pagina=$2 [L,QSA]
```

`RewriteCond` are only applicable for next `RewriteRule`.

Comment: I'm trying to add a new rule to the news page. If I put **/noticia** opens the normal page, but with no error because the ID of the GET. So the idea would be to put the message ID after the **/noticia/1**, **/noticia/2**, **/noticia/3**. New rule: `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/noticia/([^/]+)/?$ site/$1/pagina.php?pagina=pag_noticiasVer.php&id=$2 [L,QSA]`

Comment: You need to keep this new rule just below `inicio/` rule.

Comment: I need to create a condition to access the news page. Because it also must enter the ID of the news. Example **noticia?id=1** means. Ai would look like **/noticia/1**. But I can not.

Comment: I suggest you create a new question with all the details. Since extending a question from comments section is not good for future visitors. You can also include some examples and link to this question so that you get much better answer in one go.

Comment: It seems that not reading the condition that should read, and that reading the other `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ site/$1/pagina.php?pagina=$2 [L,QSA]`

Comment: The two are working conditions that helped. Only for this news it's different this not working. Speak different because it not only must open a file, but also have the ID that would be after the noticia/

Comment: Place your latest .htaccess in question. I will try one more time. If it doesn't work you need to open a new question.

Comment: `RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/site/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/inicio?$ site/$1/index.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/noticia/([^/]+)/?$ site/$1/pagina.php?pagina=pag_noticiasVer.php&id=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ site/$1/pagina.php?pagina=$2 [L,QSA]
`

Comment: That's the reason I suggested creating a new question. Edit your question and place code there not in comments.

Comment: Your 2nd rule should be: `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/noticia/([^/]+)/?$ site/$1/pagina.php?pagina=pag_noticiasVer.php&id=$2 [L,QSA]` There is no `$3` I am going for some work, will be back in an hour.

Comment: From what I am seeing the second and the third condition are conflido. Has a way of putting a rule to the third condition not read the phrase is /noticia?

Comment: Friend was right, my link was wrong, I'm changing a lot on the old site and acebei forgetting that also changed the name of some folders. Was so "pagina.php?pagina=pag_noticiasVer.php", so had to be "pagina.php?pagina=noticia"